# how to put string inside a circle using listTile in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i would like to have a circle in which i can put centered text using ListTile widget? what i done is below :

```
          ListTile(
        leading: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: color2,
            child: new Text(
              letter,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: color,
                fontSize: 17.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            )),
        title: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
        ),
        subtitle: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 2.0),
            Text(
              subtext,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 2.0),
            Text(
              date,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 2.0),
          ],
        ),
        trailing: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(
                amount,
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

and the result :

[image]

as you can see, the string is not centered vertically and i would like the do that conserving the same design. i precise, the arrow inside the circle is not an icon, but a string type variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container with Circle shape, and inside that, please center the text like below code:

```
                Container(
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                child: Center(child: Text("Your text"),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Color(0xFFe0f2f1)),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited you code so please try this and let me know.

```
ListTile(
    leading: Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Text',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    title: Text(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
    ),
    subtitle: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 2.0),
        Text(
          subtext,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 2.0),
        Text(
          date,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 2.0),
      ],
    ),
    trailing: Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            amount,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5.0),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

I hope it's work